# Laravel socialite callback url handling

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-socialite, laravel-5.4

In *Laravel Socialite Package*, I would like to get the flexible URL or flexible callback URL.

I have few different functions, such as:

- admin login
- admin register request
- user login
- user register

If an `admin register request` is called, I would like to get the data passed to the respective function of respective controller.

I am using `app('controllername')->function();` to call the handler to get the data. However, I cant get the user data.

It seems like the callback URL issue.
How do I achieve this?

Comment: Check this answer. This may help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53348777/socialite-laravel-authantication-error-with-google-api/55782862#55782862