# socialite laravel authantication error with google API

Tags: laravel, google-api, laravel-socialite

I have been using Socilte package for users login, i m using **facebook**, **google**, **twiter** and **github** API. All other API's are working fine expect **google** API, it is showing an error while returning from google.

> HTTP Error 403 - Forbidden

The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory or you do not have enough permissions to access the resource.

This is my callback function, in fact it is not reaching this callback function:

```
public function handleGoogleCallback()
{
     $user = Socialite::driver('google')->stateless()->user();        
}
```

Comment: This is my route :Route::get('/google/callback', 'Auth\LoginController@handleGoogleCallback');

Comment: Google + API is also enabled in console

Comment: I am having same issue can you guys please let me know

Answer (score 9):

I was facing the same problem couple of days back. Even googling it didn't solve my problem.
So i decided to go indepth of it and guess what, i found the appropriate reason of this issue.

In my case the reason was the word **.profile** in google callback URL.

> 'https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile' (part of my callback url)

I had a conversation with my hosting provider(Hostgator) regarding this and initially they were saying that this issue is in the code not by their side. But i had enough evidence(i did show them by changing .profile to .abc and huaa... issue gone..) to show them that this issue is from server end. Then they were pitching me for VPS hosting(i have shared hosting) but i denied to take it then finally they accepted that they have a mod_security rule that is preventing the word .profile from security reason.

They have a weired mod_security rule of course.

When i got that they are not going to change mod_security rule for me then i altered **socialite core package**

> core/vendor/laravel/socialite/src/Two/GoogleProvider.php

and commented profile here

```
protected $scopes = [
    'openid',
    //'profile',
    'email',
];
```

then everything was good except i couldn't get username because of commenting profile but for me it was good to go. So this could be a trick to get rid of bad server rules.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for getting this error is because Google+ API is not enabled, go on google console account and enable Google+ API.

Open your Google Console Account from Here:[console.developers.google.com](https://console.developers.google.com/)

Then Go to -> library -> select Google+ API -> **Enable**

---

**NOTE:** *If this is not working please change the hosting server and try it*

Comment: anybody who can help??

Comment: @AtinderSingh  hope this will help you, this is my successful code repository for [socialite](https://github.com/udhavsarvaiya/Socialite)

Comment: what are the steps to configure oAuth client in google console

Comment: @AtinderSingh I checked your website, you have not proper redirect in google

Comment: can any body try it ??

Comment: i m trying it with different redirects. The redirects are correct

Comment: and if i remove https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email+https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me+https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile from the redirected url. It works

Comment: i check your screenshot you have proper configuration, please also checked Client ID and Client secret

Comment: they are also correct as the request is reaching google api correctly ,but when returning from google , it show an error and the returned uri is : https://www.openbooktutorials.com/google/callback?state=ir2AQhn2x9ZUAEg3720OtYg9TC4FGwESH1dJcA5l&code=4/mAA4iS8rrnUtbd1X45ezgYofhht1vTUG6ES_HMdBtDHimoxvcILZg_W1Z9NQOwoVjMoos8gEpmkhaHfOyR9lWJo&scope=openid+email+profile+https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile+https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me+https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email&authuser=0&session_state=00a6b8ca1b275858b692f80321b0a7b709f4f304..e892&prompt=none

Comment: now when I remove https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile+https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me+https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email from the scope part of uri , it is working

Comment: I am facing same issue I have also enable google plus api. Can any one help me to resolve it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53725020/laravel-socialite-3-0-google-return-403-forbidden

Comment: @AtinderSingh How did u removed https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile+https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me+https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email . I visited your web site, Its working perfectly. Please help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Ramesh Go to Laravel->sociallite->src->two->GoogleProvider.php class, and edit protected scope array variable

Comment: @AtinderSingh your problem has been resolved, you can post as answer here, this will help us many users in future

Comment: protected $scopes = [
        'openid',
        'profile',
        'email',
    ];
in this variable what we have to edit? Thanks for your help @AtinderSingh.

Comment: Hi I am having same issue. Can you please let me know how to resolve this issue. Thanks

Comment: @Gurpalsingh "AtinderSingh" Got solution, he is not ready to answer here. Leave it. Don't ask here. better try to explore.

Comment: @Ramesh I tried a lot of possibilities, but I did not get success, and op know the solution but still do not want to tell it

Comment: Ok, Thanks if you will get solution then try to respond on my question 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54288961/laravel-authantication-error-with-google-api

Comment: @Gurpalsingh change the hosting server and try it

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Any solution guys? I have tried many diffferent ways but no success. Already enabled google+api