# Laravel socialite 3.0 google return 403 - Forbidden

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, google-oauth, laravel-socialite

I am using Laravel 5.6 and socialite 3.0. I have created google API from developer console and enable for Gmail API and google plus. please check screen shot.

[image]

Also, I have to make setup inside `.env` file.

> Google callback return 403 error code

I have created class and method

```
public function redirect($provieder)
{
     return Socialite::driver($provieder)->redirect();
}

public function callback($provieder)
{           
    try{
        $user = Socialite::driver($provieder)->stateless()->user();
        if (isset($user)) {
            $social = $this->createUser($user,$provieder);
            return redirect()->route('profile.fill','location');
        }
        return redirect()->route('user.signup');
    }catch (Exception $e) {
        return redirect('auth/google');
    }
 }
```

I have create route file

```
Route::get('auth/{provider}', 'OAuth\SocialController@redirect');
Route::get('auth/{provider}/callback', 'OAuth\SocialController@callback');
```

Comment: Can you share the code with us and some more information ?

Comment: @UdhavSarvaiya plz share you email id will share you code

Comment: You can add the code in your question.

Comment: @UdhavSarvaiya please check it I have added the code

Comment: Check you have proper configuration and match with your route [check here](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials)  Authorized redirect URIs and Authorized JavaScript origins

Comment: @UdhavSarvaiya i have used this url in redirect URL http://labstoclinic.com/auth/google/callback

Comment: @UdhavSarvaiya please share your email id I will share you rest of code. I have already spend lot of time

Comment: why is catch redirect again to auth/google again  ?

Comment: @AhmadElkenany if die outside try block, its also not working

Comment: @Sudhir Check this answer. This may help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53348777/socialite-laravel-authantication-error-with-google-api/55782862#55782862

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had to activate the ***Google+ API*** from the Google Developers Console.

It was indeed an HTTP 403 Forbidden response.

I learned a bit more about "ClientException"... it is thrown by Guzzle's HTTP client, and it contains a few useful properties, mainly `request` and `response`:

```
try {
    $user = Socialite::driver('google')->user();
}
catch (GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException $e) {
     dd($e->response);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This error says that the server could understand the request from the client, but it refuses to proceed with further actions with the request. It is often displayed when the server is configured to deny the client’s request for some reason.

**The causes behind 403 error page**

If the URL you’ve entered is correct, then it can be any of the following three reasons.

1) No index page

2) Empty html directory

3) *Poor permission configuration or ownership issues*.

The above listed are the most common reasons of 403 forbidden error.

check that [link](https://www.interserver.net/tips/kb/fix-403-forbidden-error/) for how to fix it

Comment: If I exit before calling createUser function. Then its also not working

Comment: @Sudhir i just checked your url but the problem not from google it's from the host

Comment: check my answer i add link (https://www.interserver.net/tips/kb/fix-403-forbidden-error/)