# Laravel google oauth 2 call back return 403 forbidden

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-socialite

I am trying to implement Google OAuth login. I will redirect to google login page. But after login it will redirect to Path defined in route with 403 error code.

http://labstoclinic.com/login/google/callback?state=access&code=4%2FtwCGdNaAZXluKqUiG4aPpUsghLLltF9hTMw9z-7ftDrcEulSSGXSpbMJv8BFgH6xD79ZrW_9NX9HalEzrDcC5Mo&scope=email+profile+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile#

Above url is browser return url.

Path defined in route file is  :

```
 Route::get('login/google/callback', 'OAuth\SocialController@googleHandleProviderCallback');
```

Callback function

```
 public function googleHandleProviderCallback()
{
    $googleUser = Socialite::driver('google')->user();
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($googleUser); exit;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your `googleHandleProviderCallback` function?

Comment: @ceejayoz I have added please check it

Comment: @Sudhir Check this answer. This may help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53348777/socialite-laravel-authantication-error-with-google-api/55782862#55782862