# laravel authantication error with google API

Tags: laravel-5

I have been using `Socilte Package` for users login, I am using Facebook and Google.

Facebook is working fine but Google API is not working,

Showing an error while returning from Google.

```
403 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory or you do not have enough permissions to access the resource
```

Error is similar to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53348777/socialite-laravel-authantication-error-with-google-api)

But I didn't found solution in this post. Google+ API is also enabled and no issue with credentials.

Domain is verified.

Comment: same problem facing. Tried lot of different possibilities but not succeed.

Comment: Check this answer. This may help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53348777/socialite-laravel-authantication-error-with-google-api/55782862#55782862